# Why can't I get the results from my inner join when using Spring JdbcClient query?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I believe the query is self-explanatory, but long story short, based on the results of a recursive CTE, I want to retrieve results from another table. The issue is `JdbcClient` does not return the results when I use multiple inner joins though I verified my query indeed returns the correct output on MySQL Workbench.

```
/**
 * Using native sql query, method returns all {@code Product} based on
 * {@code ProductCategory} and its children.
 *
 * @param categoryId is the {@code ProductCategory} and all of its children
 * @param currency is the string value of {@code SarreCurrency}
 * @param page is the of {@code org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable}
 * @return a {@code org.springframework.data.domain.Page} of {@code ProductPojo}
 * */
public Page<ProductMapper> allProductsByCategoryIdWhereIsVisibleAndInStock(
        @NotNull long categoryId,
        @NotNull SarreCurrency currency,
        @NotNull Pageable page
) {
    record Mapper(String uuid, String name, String description, String image, SarreCurrency currency, BigDecimal price) {}

    String countSql = """
    WITH RECURSIVE category (id) AS
    (
        SELECT c.category_id
        FROM product_category c
        WHERE c.category_id = :id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT pc.category_id
        FROM category cat
        INNER JOIN product_category pc
        ON cat.id = pc.parent_category_id
    )
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id)
    FROM category c1
    INNER JOIN product p ON c1.id = p.category_id;
    """;

    int totalProducts = jdbcClient.sql(countSql)
            .param("id", categoryId)
            .query(int.class)
            .single();

    String sql = """
    WITH RECURSIVE category (id) AS
    (
        SELECT c.category_id
        FROM product_category c
        WHERE c.category_id = :id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT pc.category_id
        FROM category cat
        INNER JOIN product_category pc
        ON cat.id = pc.parent_category_id
    )
    SELECT
        p.uuid AS uuid,
        p.name AS name,
        p.description AS description,
        pr.currency AS currency,
        pr.price AS price,
        p.default_image_key AS image
    FROM category c1
    INNER JOIN product p ON c1.id = p.category_id
    INNER JOIN price_currency pr ON p.product_id = pr.product_id
    INNER JOIN product_detail d ON p.product_id = d.product_id
    INNER JOIN product_sku s ON d.detail_id = s.detail_id
    WHERE d.is_visible = 1 AND s.inventory > 0 AND pr.currency = :currency
    GROUP BY pr.price, pr.currency, p.uuid, p.name, p.description, p.default_image_key
    LIMIT :size OFFSET :off;
    """;

    var list = jdbcClient.sql(sql)
            .param("id", categoryId)
            .param("currency", currency)
            .param("size", page.getPageSize())
            .param("off", page.getOffset())
            .query(Mapper.class)
            .list()
            .stream()
            .map(m -> new ProductMapper(m.uuid, m.name, m.description,
                    m.currency, m.price, m.image, "")
            )
            .toList();

    return new PageImpl<>(list, page, totalProducts);
}
```

If I can bring your attention to where my test fails `assertEquals(20, page.getNumberOfElements());`. It should return 20, but it is returning 0. I have also verified the size of the page is indeed 25 `assertEquals(25, page.getTotalElements());` but the contents is zero.

```
@Test
void allProductsByCategoryIdWhereIsVisibleAndInStock() {
    var category = categoryService
            .save(
                    ProductCategory
                            .builder()
                            .name("category")
                            .isVisible(true)
                            .parentCategory(null)
                            .categories(new HashSet<>())
                            .product(new HashSet<>())
                            .build()
            );

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        productService
                .save(
                        Product.builder()
                                .uuid(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                                .name("product 1" + (100 + i))
                                .description(new Faker().lorem().fixedString(500))
                                .defaultKey("unique-image-key" + 1)
                                .productCategory(category)
                                .productDetails(new HashSet<>())
                                .priceCurrency(new HashSet<>())
                                .build()
                );
    }

    var clothes = categoryService
            .save(
                    ProductCategory
                            .builder()
                            .name("clothes")
                            .isVisible(true)
                            .parentCategory(category)
                            .categories(new HashSet<>())
                            .product(new HashSet<>())
                            .build()
            );

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        productService
                .save(
                        Product.builder()
                                .uuid(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                                .name("product 2" + (i + 1))
                                .description(new Faker().lorem().fixedString(500))
                                .defaultKey("unique-image-key 1" + 1000)
                                .productCategory(clothes)
                                .productDetails(new HashSet<>())
                                .priceCurrency(new HashSet<>())
                                .build()
                );
    }

    var page = categoryService
            .allProductsByCategoryIdWhereIsVisibleAndInStock(
                    category.getCategoryId(),
                    SarreCurrency.NGN,
                    PageRequest.of(0, 20)
            );

    assertEquals(25, page.getTotalElements());
    assertEquals(20, page.getNumberOfElements());

    var page0 = categoryService
            .allProductsByCategoryIdWhereIsVisibleAndInStock(
                    category.getCategoryId(),
                    SarreCurrency.NGN,
                    PageRequest.of(1, 20)
            );
    assertEquals(5, page0.getNumberOfElements());
}
```